# Is libffi.pc broken on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, compiling, gcc, cross-compilation

I'm trying to cross-compile wayland (from freedesktop.org) for a Trusty Tahr armhf environment.

To set up the cross-compile I have an arm pkg-config script that properly sets PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR and PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR to point to my armhf sysroot and it's pkgconfig directories.

Inside the sysroot can be found: ~/ubuntu-core-14.04.3-core-armhf-forqemu/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libffi.pc

Inside this pkg-config file are the lines the compiler uses when it needs to link to libffi, and when it's compiling sources that depend on libffi headers:

```
Libs: -lffi
Cflags:
```

When I go to compile wayland, it's configure script properly finds libffi, but when I invoke 'make', sources that reference ffi.h fail to find the include.

Other libraries' .pc files seem to fill out the above lines with the linker directive to add a library search path, and a compiler directive to add an include path like so (libdrm.pc as an example):

```
Libs: -L${libdir} -ldrm
Cflags: -I${includedir} -I${includedir}/libdrm
```

I looked in Launchpad, and I find that libffi.pc is the same as I'm seeing here in the libffi-dev package even in wily, and even for the amd64 platform.

No one else has mentioned this issue, so I'm wondering if it's not a bug, or just a bug that seems to only rear it's head in cross-build situations (which most folks don't run into).

My goal with this question is to answer if it is a bug, and if the answer is yes, I'll file a bug in launchpad to fix it.

My guess is that because the library and include directories where libffi and it's headers are located are common directories that are typically already in compiler and linker search paths, that libffi.a/so and it's headers are just always found already implicitly by paths already included, and this situation only shows when you cross-compile.

Links to the referenced packages:

[armhf trusty libffi-dev](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/225839391/libffi-dev_3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12ubuntu0.1_armhf.deb)

[amd64 wily libffi-dev](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/211119759/libffi-dev_3.2.1-3_amd64.deb)

Comment: Just so you know: You can ask questions on Launchpad, and *convert* a question to a bug report if it turns out to be one.